# Evento de "drop" não executa a função passada!

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.listTask').forEach(task => {
    task.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    task.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
});
document.querySelectorAll('.area').forEach(area => {
    area.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    area.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    area.addEventListener('drop', drop);  //Evento que era pra ser executado!
})

function dragStart(e: Event){
    let elementEvent = e.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
    elementEvent.classList.add('drag');
}
function dragEnd(e: Event){
    let elementEvent = e.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
    elementEvent.classList.remove('drag');
}
function dragOver(){
    console.log('TA AQUI!');
}
function dragLeave(){
    console.log('PASSOU POR AQUI!');
}
function drop(){  //Função que era pra ser Executada!
    console.log('FICOU AQUI!');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Os eventos `dragenter` e `dragover` precisam ser cancelados – com `event.preventDefault()` – para indicar que o potencial alvo do drop pode aceitar os elementos que estiverem sendo arrastados.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gura3j9c/1/) do seu código corrigido.

Para mais detalhes, ver [especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#event-drag) e [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragover_event).